# Virtual Assistant -> LUIS, QnA, Dispatcher best practice

Tags: azure, nlp, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I have some question about some "best practice" for certain issues that we are facing using LUIS, QnA Maker, in particular for the Dispatcher:

1) Is there any best practice in case we have more that 15k utterances in the Dispatcher? That's looks like a limitation of the LUIS apps but the scalability of the model in the long run will be questionable.

2) Bing Spell Check for LUIS changes names and surnames for example, how to avoid this? I guess that Bing Spell Check is necessary when we are talking about ChatBots, since the typo are always behind the door, but using it for names is dangerous.

3) Cross validation is not supported out of the box, you would have split your data to folds with custom code (not difficult), use the command line to train and publish your model on your k-1/k folds, then send the k-fold utterances to the API one-by-one. Batch upload is only supported through the UI https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/551524-language-understanding-luis/suggestions/20082157-add-api-to-batch-test-model and is limited to a test set of 1,000 utterances. If we use the one-by-one approach, we pay $1,50 per 1k transactions https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/pricing/details/cognitive-services/language-understanding-intelligent-services/ and this means to get cross-validation metrics for the 5 folds for example, we could be paying about 20$ for a single experiment with our current data, more if we add more data.

4) Model is a black box, which doesn't give us the ability to use custom features if needed.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your 4th question, so that I can update the part in the answer I posted?

Comment: Regarding Custom features (point 4), I meant the use of custom embeddings we developed for our field or doing custom preprocessing for the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to address your concerns in the best possible way I can as follows:

1) As per the LUIS documentation,

[image]

Hence, you cannot exceed the limit. In case of Dispatch apps,**if the total utterance exceeds 15k, then dispatch will down sample the utterances to keep it under 15k**. There is an optional parameter([--doAutoActiveLearning](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch#creating-your-dispatch-model)) for CLI to do auto active learning which will down sample intelligently (remove non relevant utterances).

--doAutoActiveLearning: (optional) Default to false. LUIS limit on training-set size is 15000. When a LUIS app has much more utterances for training, Dispatch's auto active learning process can intelligently down sample the utterances.

2) Bing Spell Check helps users to correct misspelled words in utterances before LUIS predicts the score and entities of the utterance. However, if you want to avoid using Bing Spell Check API service, then **you will need to add the correct and incorrect spelling** which can be done in two ways:

- Label example utterances that have the all the different spellings so that LUIS can learn proper spelling as well as typos. This option requires more labeling effort than using a spell checker.
- Create a phrase list with all variations of the word. With this solution, you do not need to label the word variations in the example utterances.

3) As per the current [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-batch-testing), a maximum of 1000 utterances are allowed per test. The data set is a JSON-formatted file containing a maximum of 1,000 labeled non-duplicate utterances. You can test up to 10 data sets in an app. **If you need to test more, delete a data set and then add a new one.** I would suggest you to report it as a feature request in the [feedback forum](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/356325-general-feedback?query=luisuservoice%40microsoft.com).

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey @raunsharao, thank you for your detailed answer, quick follow up from my side:
1- Active Learning: We tried it, it works for our current data (around 20k utterances). Do you have experience or best practices for how many utterances it can handle before the accuracy starts degrading?
2- Bing Spell check: Adding phrase lists for every word that can be mispelled would be burdensome to do in a chatbot where the vocabulary used can vary a lot
3- Cross validation: We actually found out that the dispatch CLI tool does support CV (with the `dispatch eval` command), so that's no longer an issue

Comment: @TommyJimmyEmiliano I am not aware of the exact number of utterance that can be handled before the accuracy starts dipping, but would suggest you to balance your utterances across all intents for higher accuracy. However,you can have a look at the [LUIS best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-best-practices) in general to see the do's and dont's suggested. Also, if you found the answer to be helpful, can you accept it so that it helps others as well? Thanks

Comment: @ranusharao, regarding the 4th point about custom features (ex. custom embeddings or custom text preprocessing), is there any feature in LUIS for this area that we didn't notice?

Comment: @MarawanOkasha, preprocessing features(lemmatization and stemming) is currently on the roadmap. Having said that, I am not sure if you can retain the same performance or accuracy if you add custom text preprocessing.